# Keep smallest keys for distinct values in Python dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary with distinct, integer keys and potentially duplicated values, like this:

```
my_data = {5:1,2:2,3:2,4:2,1:1}
```

I know how to get the distinct values using `set()` but what I'd like to do is to select the distinct values with their key pairs, where the small occurring key among the duplicated values, like this:

```
{1:1, 2:2}
```

Comment: Python does not guarantee order of items in the dictionary. Also you call your variable `my_list`, but it is referring to a dictionary

Comment: @smac89 That's fine about it not guarantying order, I can sort post-hoc if I need to (but not a must have for this question). I can change the variable name if you like ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, group keys that have the same value in a second dictionary. Then, use a dictionary comprehension to get the minimum key for all values that have duplicate keys.

```
>>> import collections
>>> my_data = {5:1,2:2,3:2,4:2,1:1}
>>> d = collections.defaultdict(list)
>>> for k, v in my_data.items():
...    d[v].append(k)
>>> {min(keys): value for value, keys in d.items() if len(keys) > 1}
{1: 1, 2: 2}
```

(Not sure about the `if len(key) > 1`. If that's not what you meant with "among the duplicated values", then just remove that part.)

Answer (score 2):

**Sort** the dict key-value pairs by values and then keys (lower keys come first), **group** them by values, and then take the first key in each group, which will be the lowest key for that value.

You can do it in a *dictionary comprehension* without an intermediate dictionary:

```
from itertools import groupby

dct = {5:1, 2:2, 3:2, 4:2, 1:1}
new_dict = dict(next(g) for _, g in groupby(sorted(dct.items(),
                          key=lambda x: x[::-1]), lambda x: x[1]))
# {1: 1, 2: 2}
```

Comment: Or `dict(next(g) for _, g in ... )`